# Using asssembly code in ahk for execute x functions

Tags: windows, assembly, autohotkey

Is it possible to perform internal functions of a client?
for example i would like to push this to the process:
    `mov [015DC23C],00000000`
How can I execute these codes in AHK?

This is an internal function of the compiled client:

```
void Creature::turn(Otc::Direction direction) 
{ 
    // if is not walking change the direction right away 
    if(!m_walking) 
        setDirection(direction); // schedules to set the new direction when walk ends 
    else 
        m_walkTurnDirection = direction; 
}
```

I wish I could run it from AHK using memory addresses, this way I wouldn't need to use Control + Arrows which is the external way to run this function

Comment: To give you a simple example of what I want to do is the following: I want to send keystrokes to a process, but I do not want the client to detect them from windows, I want to send some instruction myself that makes the program think that I am sending a keystroke, however in my system I should not have pressed nothing.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) not sufficient? Also, don't specify question in comments; edit your question.

Comment: This is an internal function of the compiled client: `void Creature::turn(Otc::Direction direction)
{
    // if is not walking change the direction right away
    if(!m_walking)
        setDirection(direction);
    // schedules to set the new direction when walk ends
    else
        m_walkTurnDirection = direction;
}` I wish I could run it from AHK using memory addresses, this way I wouldn't need to use Control + Arrows which is the external way to run this function

Comment: [edit] your question to put those detail from comments into your actual question.  But anyway, I don't think AHK can do anything of the sort.  I think it just modifies messages at the Windows event level, without attaching to processes as a debugger to modify their memory.  Let alone to execute code inside a process, but in your case (just a MOV) it would be slightly simpler to just use a debugging system call to modify the memory directly.

Comment: So you know the exact memory address which you need to write to? Have you heard of ASLR? If you can change the client code, then expose an interface via which you can control it externally (eg. socket or so). If you cannot change the client code, then you'll have to use keys.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thanks for your reply, however some memory addresses contain values ​​which dont can be changed by something external, produce crash, so he tracked down the address which directly writes this value, the idea of ​​executing such function: `mov [015DC23C],00000000`.

Comment: @ kyrill If I find the memory address where the socket is hosted, how can I excute the function sendPacket(data*), I am aware of the way the data sent to the bytes is structured server-client

Comment: @SarahWesker: that's super weird.  Under Linux, a debugger using `ptrace` can modify even read-only memory pages in another process that would fault if the process tried to store to it normally. Are you *sure* you're using the remote-process-memory-modification system call / WinAPI function correctly, whatever it's called under Windows?

Comment: @Peter Cordes, thanks for the answer, found just what you say just now, I'm doing more research, to learn how to use those functions correctly with ahk <3 `WaitForSingleObject, VirtualAllocEx, CloseHandle, CreateRemoteThread, VirtualFreeEx`

Comment: To the person doubting AHK being able to do it, I'd like to say that that more than likely isn't true. Now I'm not going to produce the code required to prove this point, just more effort than I can be bothered with. But AHK really can do way more than someone who's maybe not very familiar with it might expect. Though, of course, it may not be the best/intended tool for the job.

Comment: And more on-topic, have you considered sending key events at a hardware driver level? To be honest, I'd guess you're more likely to succeed with that. From personal experience, I can recommend [Interception](http://www.oblita.com/interception), and if AHK will be your language of choice, there is a very nice C#-AHK wrapper for it [here](https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception).

Comment: @0x464e really interesting, definitely doing a little research on interception ;)